# Why calc library leads to strange behavior when applied to polar coordinate in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I defined a series of coordinate points in polar coordinate system in tikz, and then I use calc library to perform some operation. But the output is not what I expect. The following is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
% \usepgfplotslibrary{}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-2,xmax=2,
             ymin=-3,ymax=3,
            % unit vector ratio=1 1;
             unit vector ratio=1 1,
            ]
            \addplot[name path=A] {2};
            \addplot[name path=B] {-2};
            \draw (0,0) circle (1);
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1,...,4} {
                \coordinate (p#1) at (45*#1:1);
                \node[fill,inner sep=1pt,circle] at (p#1) {};
                \draw[name path=C] ($(p#1)+(0,-10)$)--($(p#1)+(0,10)$);%I think it should be a vertical line through point P;
                % My purpose is to obtain the intersection point of the above vertical line and y=2/-2, and connect them
                }


        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with polar coordinates but with the fact that the origins of the `axis` and the `tikzpicture` do not coincide. That is, you add points with nonzero horizontal coordinates since calc really measures the dimensions that specify the location of the coordinate relative to the origin of the `tikzpicture`. So you want to use `(axis direction cs:0,10)` instead of `(0,10)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
% \usepgfplotslibrary{}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-2,xmax=2,
             ymin=-3,ymax=3,
            % unit vector ratio=1 1;
             unit vector ratio=1 1,
            ]
            \addplot[name path=A] {2};
            \addplot[name path=B] {-2};
            \draw (0,0) circle (1);
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1,...,4} {
                \coordinate (p#1) at (45*#1:1);
                \node[fill,inner sep=1pt,circle] at (p#1) {};
                \draw[name path=C] ($(p#1)+(axis direction cs:0,-10)$)
                    --($(p#1)+(axis direction cs:0,10)$);
                %I think it should be a vertical line through point P;
                % My purpose is to obtain the intersection point of the above vertical line and y=2/-2, and connect them
                }


        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the statements in the comments in the code, you can use this to find intersections, but you can also compute the intersection points analytically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
% \usepgfplotslibrary{}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-2,xmax=2,
             ymin=-3,ymax=3,
            % unit vector ratio=1 1;
             unit vector ratio=1 1,
            ]
            \addplot[name path=A] {2};
            \addplot[name path=B] {-2};
            \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1];
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1,...,4} {
                \coordinate (p#1) at (45*#1:1);
                \node[fill,inner sep=1pt,circle] at (p#1) {};
                \path[name path=C] ($(p#1)+(axis direction cs:0,-10)$)
                    --($(p#1)+(axis direction cs:0,10)$);
                %I think it should be a vertical line through point P;
                % My purpose is to obtain the intersection point of the above vertical line and y=2/-2, and connect them
                \draw[name intersections={of=C and A,by=a#1},
                    name intersections={of=C and B,by=b#1}] 
                  (a#1) -- (b#1);    
                }
            \draw[red,dashed] let \p1=($(1,0)-(0,0)$) in 
            foreach \X in {0,1,...,4}
            {({\x1*cos(\X*45)},2) -- ({\x1*cos(\X*45)},-2)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A really a learned and smart cat.